# Заполнить datagridview второй таблицы выделенными строками из первой таблицы

Tags: c#

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Есть база в аксес, и приложение c#, на форме 2 грида, слева из базы аксеса, справа добавил сам грид, который не привязан ни к какой таблице. Как сделать, чтобы во второй таблице заголовки строки и столбца заполнялись выделенными строками в 1 таблице? Пробовал сделать так :

```
//Определяем количество выбраных строк
int n = t1DataGridView.SelectedRows.Count;
//Создаем массив этого размера для хранения названий строк
string[] labels = new string[n];
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    labels[i]=Convert.ToString(t1DataGridView.SelectedRows[i].Cells[0].Value);
}
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    dt.Columns.Add(labels[i]);
    dt.Rows.Add();
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].HeaderCell.Value = labels[i];
}
```

Но в почему то сохраняется только заголовок последней строки. Как сделать, чтобы отображались все заголовки в строке? по столбцам все вроде бы нормально.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```csharp
        //Определяем количество выбраных строк
        int n = t1DataGridView.SelectedRows.Count;

        //Создаем массив этого размера для хранения названий строк
        string[] labels = new string[n];
           DataTable dt = new DataTable();


          for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
          {
                  labels[i]=Convert.ToString(t1DataGridView.SelectedRows[i].Cells[0].Value);
              dt.Columns.Add(labels[i]);    
              dt.Rows.Add();
          }

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].HeaderCell.Value = labels[i]; 
            }
```

Comment: Все заработало, спасибо. Ещё вопросы есть: 1) при выделении, например, в 1 таблице 3 строк подряд сверху вниз, во второй таблице заголовки строк отображаются в обратном порядке, это можно исправить? 2) При нажатии на заголовок столбца для сортировки, все имена заголовков строк очищаются, здесь тоже можно как либо исправить или отключить сортировку. Вопросы не особо критичные для моей программы

Comment: @bfdbndfnd Если у Вас возник новый вопрос, задайте его при помощи кнопки "[Задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)". Если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос.